# What are SPA Aggregation approaches?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, single-page-application

I am looking for software/approach that would help to connect multiple react applications together and provide some sort of skeleton.

It would be nice if that would provide common skeleton, include navigation and state management, user customization etc.

Did anyone worked on large scale projects, where you had to create dynamic high level application?

What would be your suggestions?

Comment: Redux with react-router maybe, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes. I mean if there is a tool or application, that helps to connect multiple react components or applications (already built). Like drag and drop components, where you could pass some params to them as well. I read that Azure Portal has something like this, where you can create react components portlets. But as I said, I have little knowledge in this. So any similar approach would be helpful. I am not talking about redux or router..